# getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on @main and Exception Breakpoint DOES NOT show failing line

Tags: swift

in the past I have used exception breakpoints to help me fix bugs, but this time I'm getting an Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeeff9fe8) on @main and exception breakpoint is not showing any failing line, just main.

```
@main
struct Secret0App: App {
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding = true
```

any idea how to debug this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPbwl.png)

I know it's not a lot of info, but Xcode doesn't show me the breakpoint exception! so if you know another way to help me force Xcode to show the exception I will appreciate it

Comment: Check the log in the debugger when the crash happens - there's usually some additional information there for crashes like this.

Comment: I fixed the error. 

I changed my plist file to have a light background always

And I had a self.background in one of the views. 

I changed every single line of code until I found the root cause